# How to replace one value with another in a csv file?

Tags: python

I have a CSV file with information and want to replace the information in a specific location with a new value.

For example if my CSV file looks like this:

```
example1,example2,0

example3,example4,0

exampple5,example6,0
```

Note that each `row` is labelled for example:

```
test = row[0]

test1 = row[1]

test2 = row[2]
```

If I want to replace

`test[0]`

with a new value how would I go about doing it?

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way without installing any additional package would be to use built-in csv to read the whole file in a matrix and replace the desired element.

Here is code that would do just that:

```
import csv

with open('test.csv', 'r') as in_file, open('test_out.csv', 'wb') as out_file:
    data = [row for row in csv.reader(in_file)]
    data[0][0] = 'new value'
    writer = csv.writer(out_file)
    writer.writerows(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a handful of ways to do this, but personally I'm a big fan of pandas. With pandas, you can read a csv file with `df = pd.read_csv('path_to_file.csv')`. Make changes however you want, if you wanted row 1 column 1, you'd use `df.loc[0,0] = new_val`. Then when you are done save to the same file `df.to_csv('path_to_file.csv')`.

Comment: Forgot you'll need to add to the beginning `import pandas as pd`.